Given a partition of $r$, find the number of partitions of $s$ such that each part of $s$ is coprime to each part of $r$.
I encountered the following problem.
Suppose $r,s\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider a partition $\sum_{i=1}^k r_i$ of $r$.
Question: How many partitions $\sum_{j=1}^l s_j$ of $s$ exist such that $\operatorname{gcd}(r_i,s_j)=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq k,1\leq j\leq l$?
Example: Let $r=4,s=5$. Take the partition $2+2$ of $4$, then I want to count the partitions
$5$,
$3+1+1$ and
$1+1+1+1+1$
which yields $3$ partitions in total.
I don't necessarily need an exact number, a (good) lower bound would be enough.
From experiments I gathered that in most cases roughly half of all partitions of $s$ are valid.



partition of $4$
number of valid partitions of $5$




$4$
3


$3+1$
5


$2+2$
3


$2+1+1$
3


$1+1+1+1$
7




You metioned $s$ in the definition, but haven't used it. Is it a typo?

The construction is a bit odd.  What difference does it make what the $r_i$ sum to?  Aren't you just saying "how many ways can we partition $s$ into numbers prime to a given list of values?"  Then, given the list, we can replace it with the product of the primes dividing one or more terms in the list (or just the product of the terms, if you prefer), so now you are down to a single number.

@lulu I eventually want to count that given $r,s\in\mathbb{N}$ how many pairs of partitions of $r$ and $s$ satisfy the condition described above of being coprime to each other. That is how I derived the question above. If I would have a good lower bound for one partition of $r$, then I would only need to iterate over all partitions of $r$ to have an answer.

Intent aside, for solving the problem it's still going to be a lot easier to replace ${r_i}$ with $\text {rad}\left( \prod r_i \right)$.  Where the radical of a natural number is defined, as usual, to be the product of the distinct primes which divide that number.  That's just one test that needs to be applied, not a list of tests.  There are well known results concerning partitions into odd parts, say.  Natural to consider partitions into parts prime to $6$, say.

For any partition of $r$ consisting of even parts and 1s, the partitions of $s$ satisfying the condition are those made of odd parts, often written $q(s)$.  There are asymptotic expressions for $q(n)$ (which is much less than $p(n)$ as $n$ increases).
However, there are examples with smaller sets.  E.g., $(4,3,2,1) \in P(10)$ meets the condition for just $(11)$, $(9,1,1)$, $(7,1^4)$ (using superscripts for repetition), $(5,5,1)$, $(5,1^6)$, and $(1^11)$ in $P(11)$, i.e., the odd part partitions of 11 with no parts 3.
